# Jquery - add click event handler to <li> that are generated by autocomplete

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am using jQuery autocomplete script to pass a string value to my database which returns data in json format. From looking at firebug, the items I can click on in my autocomplete are list items with styling to remove the bullet points and to make prettier.

My problem is I want to fire a click event which captures the list item I select.

```
$("#group_name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName", "UserManager")',
                    {
                        dataType: 'json',
                        parse: function (data) {
                            var rows = new Array();
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                rows[i] = {
                                    data: data[i],
                                    value: data[i].group,
                                    result: data[i].group
                                }
                            }
                            return rows;

                        },
                        formatItem: function (row, i, max) { // loop returns autocomplete items
                            return row.group;
                        },
                        width: 300,
                        multiple: false
                    });              // End of autocomplete

$(document).ready(function () {
        chkSelection();

        $(".ac_results li").click(function (event) {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

**This is the html generated from my autocomplete javascript**

```
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 300px; top: 437.9px; left: 103.65px;" class="ac_results">
    <ul style="max-height: 180px; overflow: auto;">
        <li class="ac_even">118 Medi<strong>a</strong> ltd</li>
        <li class="ac_odd">2CV Rese<strong>a</strong>rch ltd</li>
        <li class="ac_even">7digit<strong>a</strong>l</li <li class="ac_odd">
        <strong>A</strong> br<strong>a</strong>nd<strong>a</strong>p<strong>a</strong>rt television ltd</li>
        <li class="ac_even"><strong>A</strong> Tout Fr<strong>a</strong>nce</li>
        <li class="ac_odd"><strong>A</strong>bb<strong>a</strong> Blinds</li>
        <li class="ac_even"><strong>A</strong>berdeen Journ<strong>a</strong>ls</li>
        <li class="ac_odd"><strong>a</strong>cc suspended <strong>A</strong>LF connect <strong>A</strong>lw<strong>a</strong>ys on Mess<strong>a</strong>ge</li>
        <li class="ac_even ac_over"><strong>A</strong>ccount suspended South West Medi<strong>a</strong> Group</li>
        <li class="ac_odd"><strong>A</strong>ctive Intern<strong>a</strong>tion<strong>a</strong>l</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I am not sure if its clear from my code I want to fire an event when a list item is clicked.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Use event delegation with jQuery 1.8 +

```
$(document).on('click','.ac_results li',function(){blaa,blaa,blaa});
```

This allows for the item to not be there when you add the handler.

replace `document` with closest parent element that is for sure present when your code runs.

[jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I tried your code and nothing happens. I replaced the blaa with an alert so when its clicked, an alert fires. I have a screenshot so you can see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @nickgowdy I'll put together a jsFiddle.  Give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Bluetoft answer:
If you have multiple events, you can delegate a mapped object like so:

```
$('.ac_results').on({
  click : function(){alert($(this).text()}, 
  mouseleave : function(){ //etc...} 
}, 'li');
```

I generally prefer this syntax.

Comment: your code gives me syntax errors and I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: derp. what errors? i don't see any issues with the syntax. I assume you pulled the comment out?

Answer (score 0):

The best decision is to put property methodChain at the end of widget calling:

```
`<?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'name'=>'name',
        'url'=>array('url'),
        'minChars'=>2,
        'methodChain'=>".result(function() { someFunction(); })",
    )); ?>`
```

where comFunction() is function which is called when you click on the list of autocomplete results.